# How to use pandas isin() to test values on a range of columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with 34 columns and about 10k rows. I want to keep only those rows where values are 0 or 1 in `column` `index` positions 2 through 33.

I've tried the following:

```
df = df[df.iloc[:,2:33].isin([0,1])]
```

But I get unexpected results.  Several columns are returned `NaN`.

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks...

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error in the code you posted, have a look and see if it matches the code you're actually using. Should there be a `]` at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10000, 5)*10, columns=list('ABCDE')).astype(int)
```

## Solution

```
df[((df == 0) | (df == 1)).any(axis=1)]
```

## your problem

```
 df[((df.iloc[:,2:33] == 0) | (df.iloc[:,2:33] == 1)).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: I turns out I had some data type issues.  I had previously removed the nulls, but there were a few rows where I had some whitespace characters that I missed.  Once these were gone I made all the data types int, and piRSquared's example worked.

Comment: One important thing I changed was I switched any() to all(), as:  df[(df.iloc[:,2:5] <= 1).all(axis=1)]